# I can't play my German Aladdin Broadway CD

Tags: macos, mac, music, ventura, dvd

I really liked the original soundtrack of the Aladdin Broadway musical, so I wanted to listen to all of the songs in German. I bought this (used) CD from an American company and the CD arrived today. The packaging looks new and the CD has no scratches.

However, when I tried to use my 2020 Macbook Air with Ventura to play it (using an external CD Drive), it didn't play. The drive just ejected it. I also tried playing it on a Sony boombox, but it also didn't play.

Why doesn't it play? Will I be able to get songs off of it?

Comment: CDs don’t have region codes like DVDs (movies -  NTSC or PAL), they will play on any CD player.   If it doesn’t play on your Mac or on a boombox, it’s likely a faulty CD.  If the boombox plays other CDs with no issue, the DVD is a dud.

Comment: Is there anything I can do about it or must it be returned?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is **off topic**; it’s not about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in our [help].

Comment: If it’s defective, your nly choice is to return it.

Comment: There is no need to down vote this

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding to library in itunes.
before you start, change your preferences in itunes:

prefs - General - Import settings use 'AAC encoder' and setting 'iTunes plus'.

Check the 'use error correction when reading Audio CDs' checkbox.
This will give your CD the best chance of being read by skipping over any minor flaws in the CD

now you're ready to import your CD to iTunes

File - add to library -
when it asks for the file and opens a finder window, insert the cd while holding down the command key, it should read the CD at this stage.
if it doesnt you probably have a hardware problem with your external reader or your CD is faulty.   Hope this helps.

Comment: The CD can’t be read/played with USB CD drive nor the boom box. How does the OP import a CD that can’t be read?